# My Javascript function keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, foursquare

I have a function,called `getIt()`, which finds the top 5 venues through the Foursquare API. Inside the `getVenues()`, i push the name of the first item of the venues in places array, and as it seems it exists normally inside of it. However when I call the function and set it to the variable place, I get `undefined`. What's wrong?

```js
var place=getIt();
console.log(place[0]);

function getIt(){
    var params={
        "near":"Athens,Gr",
        "query":"sushi",
        "limit":5
    }

    var places=[];
   
    foursquare.getVenues(params, function(error, venues) {        
         console.log(venues.response.venues[0].name);
         places.push(venues.response.venues[0])
         console.log(places[0].name);
    });
    //console.log(venues.response.venues[0]);
    return places;
}
```

Comment: Better to post code as a snippet over an image

Comment: It's asynchronous. The array isn't being filled until after you log.

Comment: Post code in text ....
Image is not an acceptable format

Answer (score 3):

Your code is asynchronous. It means that the function you use does not block the execution of the code following after it. You essentially send a request, but do not *wait* for it, you just say "when response arrives, populate this array with the results, if error did not occur, otherwise handle the error (which you should)". In your `getIt` function you create an array and actually return it rightaway. It will be populated later. But immediately after the execution of the `getIt` function the `places` array is empty, thus its first element is `undefined`. You have two options:

Do your manipulations inside the callback, or provide callback to the `getIt` function:

```
function getIt(params, callback) {
   foursquare.getVenues(params, function(error, venues) {
   if (!error) callback(venues)
});
}
 getIt(someParams, function(venues) {// handle venues here})
```

The other option is the `async` keyword. If you use a version of Javascript that supports it (ES6 or higher, if I remember correctly), and the foursquare API has methods returning a Promise you can give it a try